# How to use an aggregate function within a SUBQUERIES in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to perform a SUM with a subquery.

Basically, I have summarise a revenue column, x group, and now I want to summarise again that new colum.

How? I create a query in which I summarise the revenue x year, month e product category, and my idea with a subquery summarise again that colum

Following my code:

```
SELECT sum (revenue)
FROM
(select YEAR(orderdate), catcode, MONTH(orderdate), SUM(linetotal) as revenue
from factSales
    inner join dimProducts on factSales.prodno = dimProducts.prodno
    group by YEAR(orderdate), catcode, MONTH(orderdate))
```

But i received an error message "error with )"

Thanks in advance

(I do not know how to add my dataset)

Comment: May need an alias for your subquery / derived table, depends on your RDBMS.  But, I'd go ahead and try adding one, ie. at the very end: `... MONTH(orderdate)) a`

Comment: No sub-query needed, just SUM() without a GROUP BY.